# E2010 Incompatible types

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I have two units:

```
unit D8;

interface

uses Darbas;

const
Ilgis = 100;
type
Tmas = array[1..Ilgis] of integer;
```

and

```
unit Darbas;

interface
const
  Ilgis = 100;
type
  Tmas = array[1..Ilgis] of integer;

procedure Ieskoti(X:Tmas; m:byte; var nr:byte);
```

I do call `procedure Ieskoti` in `unit D8` button click event:

```
procedure TfrmD8.btn4Click(Sender: TObject);
var
nr : Byte;
begin
  Ieskoti(A, n, nr);  //HERE I GET ERROR
end;
```

and i do get error:

> [dcc32 Error] D8.pas(130): E2010 Incompatible types: 'Darbas.Tmas' and
> 'D8.Tmas'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is how Delphi's type system works.

If you define two (static or dynamic) array types at two different places, they will *not* be assignment-compatible, even if they are "identical".

You need to define your type

```pascal
type
  Tmas = array[1..Ilgis] of Integer;
```

*once* and then refer to this type every time you need it.

For instance, you can choose to define it in `Darbas`. Then remove the type definition from `D8` and instead include `Darbas` in `D8` using a `uses` clause, which you already do.

```pascal
unit Darbas;

interface

const
  Ilgis = 100;

type
  Tmas = array[1..Ilgis] of Integer;

procedure Ieskoti(X: Tmas; m: Byte; var nr: Byte);
```

and

```pascal
unit D8;

interface

uses Darbas;
```

Everything from the `interface` section of `Darbas` will now be visible in `D8`, including the `Ilgis` constant and the `Tmas` type.

Comment: If other code uses `D8` and expects to find `Ilgis` and `tMas` in it, you can define aliases for the symbols in `Darbas`, eg: `unit D8; interface uses Darbas; const Ilgis = Darbas.Ilgas; type Tmas = Darbas.Tmas;`

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Thank you for pointing out to aliases.